# How to apply default value in NgStyle in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I use this to change background of an element.

`[style.background-color]="condition ? 'red' : 'green'"`

But since I am going to use themes - I wont know whats current `default` background colour is..

how should I rewrite the above to support an arbitrary theme style?

Comment: sorry, the question is not super clear, you want to use theme colors instead of 'red' and 'green'? if that's not the question than I don't get what you're asking, if you put that ngStyle there then nothing else matters and you get a red or green background color.

Answer (score 0):

set the default background just before the `[style.background-color]="condition ? 'red' : 'green'"`

so, the code will be
`style="background-color:blue" [style.background-color]="condition ? 'red' : 'green'"`

here the blue is default

Comment: but it will never have a blue background as the one with the condition will always override it, so again the background is going to be either red or green no matter what.

Comment: the whole point of the question - i dont know what colour is default. but thanks for the effort

Answer (score -1):

actually it is simple:

`[style.background-color]="condition ? 'red' : null"`